# How to use guard with foreman?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bdd, guard

Given the [guard-rails](https://github.com/guard/guard-rails) gem is an easy way to start a rails server and to relaunch it automatically during development as the source files change;

how should this gem be used to launch the processes in a Procfile instead of having it run `rails s`?

I have already found the [foreman](https://github.com/ddollar/foreman) gem, which can read and start each process listed in the Procfile with `foreman start`.

Thanks! -A

#### Edit 1

This is a bad approach. Each process should be managed individually by guard so that they can

- be restarted independently, and
- be launched with development-friendly flags

Comment: It might be worth asking this on http://meta.stackoverflow.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could fork the gem and add your changes to the RailsRunner that has a hardcoded command:

```
  %{sh -c 'cd #{Dir.pwd} && rails s #{rails_options.join(' ')} &'}
```

https://github.com/guard/guard-rails/blob/master/lib/guard/rails/runner.rb